# MySQL per shift counter query

Tags: mysql

I'm looking for some advice with a query I'm trying to write. I would like to count the occurrence (number of rows) of a column based on whose shift (6-2, 2-10 & 10-6) it falls into. The trouble is the shifts rotate every two weeks, e.g. if I just started on the 6-2 in two weeks time I would be on the 10-6. I have a query that will count said occurrence depending on the shift but I cannot get my head around how to make it count based on whos shift it happened on.

Any advice would be very helpful!

Thanks in advance.

Edit:

Table headings

Serial Number | Date & Time | Part Number | Type | Result

Edit 2 (a bit more detail):

I would like to count how many instances of unknown occur in part number for each our shifts. The part number column contains various numbers (always length 8) identifying the product running through the machine. If the machine for whatever reason doesn't see or read the part number correctly it writes unknown to the table.

e.g.

Week 13: Tom is on 6-2 shift / Alex is on 2-10 shift / Cam is on 10-6

Week 15: Alex is on 6-2 shift / Cam is on 2-10 / Tom is on 10-6 shift

Week 17: Cam is on 6-2 / Tom is on 2-10 shift / Alex is on 10-6 shift.

This pattern continues indefinitely and I want to some the number of unknowns in part number for Cam's shift, Tom's shift and Alex's shift. So I should end up with three numbers. I hope this helps.

Comment: Somewhere in your db you must know who is on what shift when?

Comment: Unfortunately its not recorded in our DB.

Comment: Then all you can do is count the occurrences by shift.. Or perhaps I haven't understood please add sample data and desire outcome as text and read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. Could you try to clarify it? I know, you only half understand the problem yourself, and therefore it is difficult to explain. But we're missing essential information. We cannot see your database, so all we have is the information you give us.

Comment: Use `SUM(time BETWEEN lowerbound AND upperbound)` instead of COUNT().

Comment: Apologies for not really explaining very well. I'll try again;

Comment: Just added a bit more info to the main question

Comment: I think the counting the unknown instances is less relevant. It is more about whether you can work out whos shift it is from the Date & time (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.000) based on a repeating pattern.

Comment: I'll try to give an answer. Not sure if I can....

Comment: Because you still don't understand or because you don't think it is possible or both?

Comment: Week numbers are not stored (Apparently) so what is your week number based on? Calendar date or some internal company start of year date?

Comment: We just pull the week number from the Pdate using: @current_WEEK int = DATEPART(wk, GETDATE()). So to answer your question, yes calendar date.

Comment: I gave a partial answer. It's too difficult to work this all out without actually having a database to work with.

Answer (score 0):

OK, so we can [get the week number in MySQL](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-week/). For instance:

```
WEEK(<Date & Time colum>, 1)
```

have a look at the link above to decide which mode you need.

There are three shifts and three workers. I'll give them numbers:

```
Tom  = 0
Alex = 1
Cam  = 2

6-2  = 0
2-10 = 1
10-6 = 2
```

I then get this pattern:

| week | shift | worker | rotation |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 0 | 2 | 2 | 0 |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 | 0 | 1 |
| 2 | 0 | 2 | 2 |
| 2 | 1 | 0 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 0 | 0 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 | 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 2 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

Now we need to try and compute the 'shift' and 'worker' numbers from the 'week' number. Let's start with the 'shift'. There is no way to get it from week, we just have to define it:

```
SET shift0 = 0
SET shift1 = 1
SET shift2 = 2
```

This seems pointless, but bear with me. Now we need to compute the workers. How would we do this, given the 'week' and 'shift'? Here we have to use [modulo](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-math-functions/mysql-mod/) 3:

```
SET worker0 = MOD('week' + 'shift0', 3)
SET worker1 = MOD('week' + 'shift1', 3)
SET worker2 = MOD('week' + 'shift2', 3)
```

Written full out with the WEEK() function:

```
SET worker0 = MOD(WEEK(<Date & Time colum>, 1) + 0, 3)
SET worker1 = MOD(WEEK(<Date & Time colum>, 1) + 1, 3)
SET worker2 = MOD(WEEK(<Date & Time colum>, 1) + 2, 3)
```

This is as far as I am willing to take it.

I would try to reconstruct the missing information using the above and store it in the database. Create tables to hold the workers and the shifts. Otherwise you'll have to write very complicated queries, which is not what you want.

Comment: Sorry got dragged away, thanks for your help. I should be able to fill in the blanks I'll let you know with what I finish with!

Comment: @KERRmit Don't worry. It's not my best answer ever, but I hope it gets you going. The basic problem here seems to be missing information about shifts and workers. You can either create it every time in your queries, or create tables containing the information. I prefer the latter because I don't like complex queries.

Comment: @KERRmit The +0, +1 and +2 represent the shift, as explained a bit above it.